# Fixed Scrollable Sidebar with Fixed Navbar in Container - Tailwind CSS

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to put a fixed navbar inside my main container that doesn't overlap with the fixed sidebar (using Tailwind CSS) but everything I try isn't working. Hoping someone can help me. I made a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve here: https://prnt.sc/125jb3o

Here is what I have so far, the sidebar is working and the main content is scrolling, but I can't figure out how to put a fixed navbar in the main container.

```
<div class="h-screen flex">
          
<!-- Fixed sidebar -->
<div class="bg-blue-400 w-80 overflow-y-scroll pl-3">
  I am the logo<br/><br/>
@include('layouts.sidebar')
</div>

<!-- Scroll wrapper -->
<div class="flex-1 flex overflow-hidden">
<!-- Scrollable container -->
                
  <div class="flex-1 overflow-y-scroll bg-gray-100">
  <main>
   <I-WANT-NAVBAR-FIXED-HERE>
    {{$slot}}
  </main>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to play around with `min-h-* max-h-*` and `flex & flex-1`. See a [working example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/0xHtD5d3xZ).

```
<div class="min-h-screen max-h-screen flex overflow-hidden">
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div class="flex w-64 bg-gray-100 overflow-auto">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus repellat eaque nobis, illum saepe iure perspiciatis eligendi eos assumenda quos adipisci officiis porro est hic laborum consequuntur deleniti. Dolor, amet! Libero provident numquam recusandae debitis laboriosam ut repellat repellendus quas minima id voluptate velit dignissimos tempore excepturi saepe quo, voluptatum optio ratione quis ipsa sequi! Cupiditate placeat dolores neque similique? Nisi soluta repellat laborum itaque autem ad quidem reprehenderit labore corrupti, totam earum ea! Voluptatem id placeat quaerat, minima quibusdam aperiam aut consequuntur impedit similique deleniti pariatur rem ea nam? Eligendi sint non optio placeat voluptate, totam vitae quo sequi dolore in dolores inventore officia quas vero repudiandae harum molestiae rem temporibus quae, expedita ea accusantium neque cum odit? Nobis. Magni, laborum, tempore aliquam inventore facere mollitia fugit fuga consequuntur eligendi libero quisquam hic nemo repellat in non illum? Consequatur, consectetur. Recusandae optio repellendus voluptatum quam dolorem alias, doloremque excepturi. Maiores minus architecto error aliquam voluptas, et totam. Atque inventore animi totam modi earum adipisci veniam officiis odio, iusto, alias autem quidem. Cupiditate consequatur ipsam atque, dolorum fugit beatae nemo. Dolor magni maiores atque quo recusandae, asperiores quos autem aut, cupiditate accusamus laudantium delectus consectetur ipsum ad itaque ratione repudiandae vitae unde dolorum sint aperiam non. Maxime officiis harum laborum? Quas, numquam. Aspernatur adipisci eos eum id consectetur dolores porro at iure consequuntur. Eius ullam minima earum iure vero velit, aut voluptatum pariatur cum perspiciatis sunt illum necessitatibus, animi incidunt? Corrupti, praesentium distinctio fugiat, eius consequatur libero facere, cum repudiandae nemo ducimus aliquid ab sapiente quos asperiores ullam molestiae. Quo commodi aspernatur natus quaerat sequi eveniet dicta, rem exercitationem ipsum? Alias, placeat voluptates dolores ipsam esse vel id earum quidem enim totam repudiandae excepturi doloribus reiciendis dolor deserunt quas ullam facilis omnis expedita vero labore tempore nesciunt voluptatibus. Saepe, laboriosam. Expedita, sapiente. Est saepe fuga inventore assumenda delectus cum iste. Quas maiores nihil minima modi, omnis quisquam blanditiis architecto vitae? Quas tenetur, quam veritatis dolorum doloribus distinctio dicta. Quod, ea. Optio explicabo cum eligendi deserunt a beatae. Doloremque, velit! Ratione odit qui earum? Molestias, adipisci quis! Non quisquam iste nesciunt maxime magnam quod. Sunt, sequi nostrum laboriosam vitae id temporibus. Suscipit earum dolorem dignissimos nemo voluptatem fugit ratione aliquid, modi magni necessitatibus maxime debitis, reiciendis repudiandae quia ullam vitae, officiis totam! Aliquid praesentium laudantium officia sapiente quasi ab optio cum? Omnis ipsam aperiam aut iure quae non minus esse eius quia laboriosam delectus, illo ab. Nostrum harum, est, reprehenderit a quisquam porro sunt cum rerum ullam incidunt aut, repudiandae nemo. Voluptatibus illum, facilis soluta hic non et eaque sint esse doloribus ullam? Dolorem ab eveniet officia distinctio. Cupiditate, vitae quas aspernatur doloribus suscipit, libero ea eveniet repudiandae ratione eligendi qui! Magnam sunt cumque, beatae neque autem numquam, fugit unde perferendis dignissimos pariatur obcaecati perspiciatis quibusdam? Neque, cumque expedita esse voluptas, officia hic nisi, deleniti corrupti ut iste dolor quia autem. Magnam placeat error maxime similique ipsa, iusto at debitis aspernatur excepturi architecto non reprehenderit, numquam quis iure quasi ipsum tempore cupiditate exercitationem nisi, cumque nam! Iure veniam delectus aut minima! Sequi animi culpa, quidem nulla, necessitatibus eveniet temporibus magnam minus repellat ad obcaecati enim quae provident rerum vero, nostrum est in minima voluptas. Voluptates maxime, praesentium voluptas nisi ad doloribus. Commodi minus dignissimos amet vitae iste, temporibus aperiam libero inventore corrupti sunt delectus similique fugit eum debitis distinctio pariatur autem iusto. Natus fugiat molestias amet cupiditate quos obcaecati vel tenetur. Voluptate, pariatur minima? Dicta nam pariatur illo doloremque distinctio amet voluptatum maxime mollitia. Mollitia blanditiis, quidem eum voluptatibus molestiae numquam libero! Aliquam in nobis et enim non, error illo rem!</div>

  <div class="flex flex-1 flex-col bg-gray-200 overflow-hidden">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="flex h-16 bg-gray-300"></div>

    <!-- Main -->
    <div class="flex flex-1 overflow-auto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus rerum corporis, animi tempora totam distinctio soluta fuga aliquid quos! Impedit molestias libero non aperiam nostrum ut quod quia iusto delectus? Iusto repellat ipsum sit quas provident maxime totam et facere. Aspernatur, sunt. Voluptas placeat quos odio reiciendis possimus voluptatem nostrum unde, corporis suscipit aspernatur recusandae, eveniet dolore, doloremque distinctio saepe. Iste dolores, veniam sint eum libero provident, itaque, quibusdam enim laborum sapiente minima quasi. Ut ad obcaecati neque atque perspiciatis? Magnam qui tempora odio assumenda blanditiis animi est, placeat saepe? Perspiciatis, modi amet. Dolores doloremque fugiat, accusamus quibusdam cum quidem inventore laborum at quae cumque nemo blanditiis delectus commodi tempore molestiae veniam. Ex nihil dolore aspernatur doloremque, id optio veniam. Illum quas corrupti pariatur molestias corporis, culpa possimus magni. Architecto eveniet ullam soluta exercitationem, eos nostrum ducimus doloremque? Soluta delectus consequuntur quisquam. Corporis ducimus eum iste quam corrupti ex ad! Aliquid quasi magnam aut, vitae dolorum commodi iste autem, pariatur, iure repellat cum necessitatibus officia sit nemo reprehenderit neque! Dolorem necessitatibus soluta impedit ut ad unde sed asperiores consectetur ipsam? Nisi dicta non illo obcaecati numquam? Explicabo quisquam fugit eos voluptates optio laudantium, provident suscipit at officia illo sit modi impedit iusto earum alias necessitatibus eum vel quidem ea? Quis. Nam, dolorum. Eveniet explicabo dicta sed cumque tempore dignissimos inventore rem numquam asperiores consequuntur! Ullam aspernatur tempora cumque ad molestias dignissimos repellendus assumenda porro quo necessitatibus voluptate, autem eum quasi. Aspernatur ea perferendis pariatur placeat dicta magnam quas nobis esse tempora ducimus? Voluptatum corporis facere, id aperiam et repellendus distinctio veniam, maxime necessitatibus vitae at quae dolorem nam corrupti dolor. Repellat sunt, quae eum modi, ex necessitatibus natus dignissimos, doloremque neque sint consequatur. Asperiores, delectus adipisci. Neque quam hic non omnis odio, voluptate cum corporis, earum, harum provident saepe commodi! Eaque qui labore a eveniet ea vel officia, facere sint nesciunt sapiente molestias distinctio deserunt dolore excepturi tempore laborum optio nemo quidem iusto exercitationem! Rem cum ex quas quasi cupiditate? Rerum fugiat eveniet laborum corporis quasi, accusantium assumenda explicabo eligendi neque consequuntur ea exercitationem fugit, repellat quae dicta quas, sunt fuga expedita consectetur. Nobis, natus perferendis amet iusto laboriosam voluptas? Optio temporibus pariatur rem praesentium a minus necessitatibus ad alias neque deserunt beatae eos, quae sunt quibusdam reprehenderit cum autem magni perspiciatis ipsa! Nam eligendi incidunt aperiam, vel corporis ea! Sequi, aut sed quisquam esse placeat voluptate. Culpa error debitis dolor velit, tempora sint quia voluptas totam deserunt. Quos cumque accusantium dolore expedita, necessitatibus pariatur. Rerum repudiandae eveniet quibusdam? Non. Ipsa saepe incidunt blanditiis provident, suscipit minima consectetur harum aspernatur deleniti eius quod labore ab dicta vero velit! Quam aperiam esse quo dolorem vel ipsam quos mollitia obcaecati sint temporibus. Voluptate dignissimos temporibus accusamus reiciendis repellendus non sit voluptatem! Odio sit voluptatum, aliquid suscipit asperiores tenetur consectetur delectus sint dignissimos vel fugiat, inventore corporis vero. In veniam illo debitis esse? Obcaecati libero vero, corrupti veniam autem sint inventore quas eligendi! Provident, a eveniet obcaecati sunt minima ratione fugiat ut reiciendis dignissimos accusantium consequuntur accusamus, incidunt illum quos eligendi. Magni, corporis. Tenetur veniam possimus earum tempora fuga eius consequatur fugit repellat assumenda? Aliquid eaque libero iste? Autem dolore, voluptates eum sint dicta sit ducimus aspernatur perspiciatis id et vero, quisquam ratione. Voluptas quaerat laudantium dicta ab at? Excepturi quidem eveniet repellendus vero officiis sequi quo laborum. Fugiat sapiente asperiores molestiae architecto necessitatibus maiores eveniet doloremque laudantium? Architecto ad iste ipsum culpa! Omnis, voluptatibus dignissimos voluptate dicta fuga hic molestias provident fugit velit accusantium amet neque quod debitis error vero nostrum eum quasi, illo quam suscipit? Tempore soluta cupiditate maxime nihil consectetur! Ut deleniti eius, doloribus nesciunt minima non inventore fugit sed recusandae placeat illo maxime praesentium unde fuga nisi, tempora repellendus, in sunt quidem laudantium dignissimos? Accusamus fuga suscipit in omnis. Illum pariatur ipsa facere inventore deserunt hic id modi, quidem dolorem praesentium fugiat, facilis nobis incidunt odit veritatis fuga aliquid accusamus vel magnam quas. Obcaecati dolores id quisquam maiores omnis. Incidunt temporibus eius quisquam reprehenderit, repellat veritatis molestias facere sed tempore harum cupiditate magnam perferendis voluptates blanditiis eos consequatur dolorem fuga quaerat. Illo officiis animi quisquam itaque in ea repudiandae. Explicabo, similique, repellendus animi omnis impedit ratione modi eos quos debitis fugit quaerat officiis tempore sed dicta non maiores a mollitia. Et quae dolore nisi voluptas explicabo, laborum ducimus suscipit. Harum veritatis dolor dolores fugit odio reprehenderit saepe quasi sed voluptatum nesciunt impedit labore quas ducimus officiis animi laudantium accusantium quisquam numquam cupiditate odit qui debitis laborum, sint in. Numquam? Quas ut quo corporis eligendi iure nesciunt assumenda! Aut quo iure adipisci rem minus distinctio ipsa, incidunt alias tempora dolorum, beatae sint, numquam cum maiores! Rem reprehenderit non sed nulla? Enim, eos temporibus? Aspernatur est iusto dignissimos molestiae perspiciatis alias exercitationem nemo illo dolor autem. Nam quaerat facere officia dicta unde commodi, possimus ipsa distinctio, ad, odit est laboriosam cupiditate. Beatae alias quis quaerat illo commodi rerum eos officiis quibusdam harum, voluptatem enim porro praesentium libero, possimus maxime nihil vel. Labore molestias tempora perspiciatis quis veniam error sed magnam quas. Sit nihil itaque placeat dolores possimus expedita, nisi aliquid recusandae adipisci? Ab corrupti itaque animi voluptates exercitationem possimus, assumenda, saepe autem in, natus error. Magnam possimus nihil maiores dolorem rerum. Cumque nesciunt, ab possimus consectetur doloribus provident delectus quis, debitis praesentium repellendus beatae dolorum! Tempore sed molestias nostrum totam accusamus corporis, quos laborum dicta ipsa eveniet perspiciatis, vel iusto iste. Laboriosam earum, nesciunt ad et assumenda molestiae a! Reprehenderit provident autem, et est earum impedit tenetur aut esse id laudantium cumque magnam obcaecati ipsum mollitia molestiae repellat in deserunt quo. Unde quidem consequatur beatae officiis at nisi sequi reiciendis suscipit laboriosam labore iure maxime, autem aperiam omnis impedit alias sit voluptatum? Ea assumenda aliquam voluptatum unde porro repudiandae mollitia atque. Nulla suscipit, eveniet, impedit voluptas nam cum minus nemo incidunt illo dolore laudantium magni dicta nihil cumque hic similique voluptates! Tempore, voluptate. Labore fugit dolore adipisci, dolorum nulla libero pariatur. Eum, nemo totam debitis sapiente eligendi expedita architecto perferendis a atque aperiam quaerat inventore alias ullam culpa laborum, ea labore ut corporis quidem pariatur provident rerum blanditiis sunt! Autem, illum. Nemo illum possimus sit deleniti dolore placeat aliquam ipsum asperiores modi minus provident suscipit, ex soluta? Reprehenderit iure eaque animi, neque pariatur illo maxime accusamus inventore mollitia assumenda beatae? Delectus? Eveniet numquam aliquid temporibus quidem saepe architecto et at! Repudiandae minima consequuntur similique minus, unde, vero cumque voluptate aut dolorum numquam dignissimos nemo natus iure inventore voluptates consequatur voluptatum nam? Quia expedita veritatis quaerat sunt rem inventore dolore quod aperiam vero pariatur quae quidem possimus et repellendus quas dicta minima corporis veniam, tempore voluptate tempora incidunt optio! Eos, reiciendis quaerat! Fugit, voluptatem nostrum? Quod corrupti et praesentium architecto, cumque aperiam aspernatur, neque unde minus porro minima esse similique alias saepe repellendus adipisci! Illum natus excepturi omnis odio at iste soluta. Voluptatibus sapiente, non aspernatur nobis distinctio iste incidunt. Mollitia neque placeat culpa deserunt facilis porro est voluptas beatae molestiae suscipit, dolores consequuntur? Perspiciatis ad, perferendis officia dolorum facere error quibusdam. Voluptatibus ipsum, amet quas, vel eligendi provident facilis molestias veniam totam sequi, sapiente deserunt illum earum voluptates. Alias tempora numquam ut, perferendis aspernatur asperiores odio eveniet! Quasi quam sapiente itaque?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```